# If Cell Is Blank, Fill With Other Cell’s Text Data

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

This is probably simple for you experts out there. I've tried so many ways, and in so many locations w/in the code, but none are working for me. Please help!

All I’m trying to do is get data from **CELL RANGE B4:B4000** to copy automatically to **CELL RANGE J4:J4000** *should* **CELL RANGE J4:J4000** be ***empty***.

FYI: Data being inputted via a user-form.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CmdButton_CONTINUE1_Click() 

Dim TargetRow As Integer
Dim FullName As String   'Variable for FULL NAME = CELL RANGE J4:J4000
Dim QBFileName As String   'Variable Quick Books File Name = CELL RANGE B4:B4000
Dim UserMessage As String

FullName = Txt_Client_First_Name & " " & Txt_Client_LAST_Name
QBFileName = Txt_QB_File_Name

'begin check if EDIT or ADD New Entry Mode
If Sheets("Engine").Range("B4").Value = "NEW" Then  'ADD New Entry Mode


'BEGINS VALIDATION CHECK: IF in "ADD New Entry Mode" mode to prevent duplicate FULL NAME J Column entries

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Database").Range("J3:J4000"), FullName) > 0 Then

MsgBox "Client's Full Name already exists", 0, "Check" 
Exit Sub 

End If  'ends validation check OF Duplicate FULLNAME (J Column)


'BEGINS VALIDATION CHECK: IF in "ADD New Entry Mode" to prevent duplicate QBFileName B Column entries

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Database").Range("B3:B4000"), QBFileName) > 0 Then

MsgBox "QuickBooks File Name already exists", 0, "Check" 
Exit Sub 

End If
~~~~
```

Comment: *Posted:
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/1216775-if-a-cell-is-blank-fill-with-other-cell%C2%92s-text-data*

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CmdButton_CONTINUE1_Click()

Dim TargetRow As Integer
Dim FullName As String   'Variable for FULL NAME = CELL RANGE J4:J4000
Dim QBFileName As String   'Variable Quick Books File Name = CELL RANGE B4:B4000
Dim UserMessage As String

FullName = Txt_Client_First_Name & " " & Txt_Client_LAST_Name
QBFileName = Txt_QB_File_Name

'begin check if EDIT or ADD New Entry Mode
If Sheets("Engine").Range("B4").Value = "NEW" Then  'ADD New Entry Mode


'BEGINS VALIDATION CHECK: IF in "ADD New Entry Mode" mode to prevent duplicate FULL NAME J Column entries

If 1 + UBound(Split(Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("J3:J4000")), Chr(1)), " ", Chr(2)), Chr(1), " ")))) > 0 Then

MsgBox "Client's Full Name already exists", 0, "Check"
Exit Sub

End If  'ends validation check OF Duplicate FULLNAME (J Column)


'BEGINS VALIDATION CHECK: IF in "ADD New Entry Mode" to prevent duplicate QBFileName B Column entries

If 1 + UBound(Split(Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("B3:B4000")), Chr(1)), " ", Chr(2)), Chr(1), " ")))) > 0 Then

MsgBox "QuickBooks File Name already exists", 0, "Check"
Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Ronan,

Thanks so much.  This code was much more complicated than I had expected.  However, it didn't work.  :(  

Problem:  every new entry says Full Name exists.  

I copied your code and replace my line of code with it, but no such luck.

Comment: MUMPS in Ozgrid solved this!

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/1216775-if-a-cell-is-blank-fill-with-other-cell%C2%92s-text-data

Answer (score 0):

**MUMPS** in Ozgrid solved this!

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/1216775-if-a-cell-is-blank-fill-with-other-cell%C2%92s-text-data

YEA!!!  THANKS MUMPS!